# intersection of sigma algebras is a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I am new to $\sigma$-algebras and I am having some conceptual difficulty with the proof regarding the fact that an intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is again a sigma algebra. So formally the question is this

Let $X$ be a set.

let $\{\mathcal{H}_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of $\sigma$-algebras on $X$.

Prove that $\mathcal{H}=\bigcap \{\mathcal{H}_{i};i \in I \}$ is again a $\sigma$-algebra.

So the proof is to go through the Axioms 1 by 1  (though my issue with the proof revolves mainly around the first axiom).

From the first Axiom of sigma algebras as $X \in \mathcal{H}_{i}$ for all $i \in I$. Hence We see that  $X \in \mathcal{H}$ by definition of the intersection $\Box $.

**Here is my issue.**

I don't see how we know that $X \in \mathcal{H}$ just by the definition of the intersection, i.e. how do we know that $X \notin \bigcup \{\mathcal{H}_{i};i \in I \}\setminus  \bigcap \{\mathcal{H}_{i};i \in I \}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition:

> Let $(A_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be an indexed family of sets. We have:
>   $$x \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda \iff x \in A_{\lambda}, \forall \lambda \in \Lambda$$

In your case, $\mathcal{H_i}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra for every $i \in I$ so $X \in \mathcal{H}_i$ by the first axiom.

Therefore $$X \in \bigcap_{i\in I} \mathcal{H_i} = \mathcal{H}$$