# Is $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$ a $\sigma$ algebra? Is there always really the maximum element $E$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am reading a famous book by Kolmogorov and Fomin (4th Edition, translated from Russian to Japanese).

> Definition:
> Let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a non-empty set of sets.
> $\mathfrak{B}$ is called a $\sigma$ algebra when $\mathfrak{B}$ satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - If $A\in\mathfrak{B}, B\in\mathfrak{B}$, then $A\triangle B\in\mathfrak{B}, A\cap B\in\mathfrak{B}$.
> - If $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n,\dots$ are elements of $\mathfrak{B}$, then $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\in\mathfrak{B}$.
> - There is an element $E\in\mathfrak{B}$ such that $A\cap E=A$ for any element $A\in\mathfrak{B}$.

My question is the following:

> Let $\mathfrak{S}$ be a non-empty set of sets.
> Let $\Sigma=\{\mathfrak{B} | \mathfrak{B} \text{ is a }\sigma \text{ algebra which contains }\mathfrak{S} \}$.
> Is $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$ a $\sigma$ algebra?

***I cannot show that there is an element $E\in\displaystyle \bigcap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$ such that $A\cap E=A$ for any element $A\in\displaystyle \bigcap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$.***

By the way, I asked the following question:
[Is there a $\sigma$ algebra $\mathfrak{B}$ such that $\mathfrak{S}\subset\mathfrak{B}$ and $\bigcup_{A\in\mathfrak{S}}A\notin\mathfrak{B}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4092331)

The authors proved the following theorem (Theorem 4) in this book:

> Definition:
> Let $\mathfrak{S}$ be a non-empty set of sets.
> Let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a $\sigma$ algebra such that $\mathfrak{S}\subset\mathfrak{B}$.
> If $E=\displaystyle \bigcup_{A\in\mathfrak{S}}A$, then $\mathfrak{B}$ is called an $\mathfrak{S}$-irreducible $\sigma$ algebra.

> Theorem 4:
> Let $\mathfrak{S}$ be a non-empty set of sets.
> Then, there is a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{B}(\mathfrak{S})$ such that $\mathfrak{S}\subset\mathfrak{B}(\mathfrak{S})\subset\mathfrak{B}^*$ for any $\mathfrak{S}$-irreducible $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{B}^*$.

Comment: Did you make any attempt to prove any of these properties? If I’m not mistaken that object is just the sigma algebra generated by a collection of sets

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera I cannot show that there is an element $E\in\cap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$ such that $A\cap E=A$ for any element $A\in\cap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the definition of $\sigma$ algebra in this book different from the standard definition of $\sigma$ algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092460/is-the-definition-of-sigma-algebra-in-this-book-different-from-the-standard-d)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I want an example for which $\cap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$ is not a $\sigma$ algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a set $\mathfrak S$ such that there is a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak B_0$ with $A := \bigcup \mathfrak S \notin \mathfrak B_0$ but $\mathfrak S \subseteq \mathfrak B_0$ (for example the sets in the answer to your linked question).

$\mathfrak B_0$ and the power set $\mathcal P(A)$ of $A$ are two of the $\sigma$-algebras in $\Sigma$. As
$$
  \mathfrak B_? := \bigcap_{\mathfrak B \in \Sigma} \mathfrak B
$$ is a subset of both of them, it does not contain $A$ but all its elements are subsets of $A$, i.e. $\mathfrak B_?$ consists of proper subsets of $A$. On the other hand, a maximal element of $\mathfrak B_?$ would have to contain all elements of $A$ (since $\mathfrak B_?$ includes $\mathfrak S$), i.e. it needs to be a superset of $A$.

Therefore, the set $\mathfrak B_?$ is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra again.

Comment: Eike Schulte, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a slightly different definition of $\sigma$-algebras as usually common. But as for two sets $A,B$ holds $A\setminus B=A\triangle(A\cap B)$ and $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ holds, Kolmogorov's definition is equivalent to the common one. The set which is denoted by $E$ in Kolmogorov's definition is the set $\Omega$ in the standard definition, which is also sometimes called as 'universe'. Thus a $\sigma$-algebra in the sense of Kolmogorov is usually denoted as a *$\sigma$-algebra over the set $\Omega=E$*.

The [intersection of $\sigma$-algebras over the same set $\Omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694099/intersection-of-sigma-algebras-is-a-sigma-algebra) is always a $\sigma$-algebra. This also explains what the set $E=\Omega$ is you are looking for to be in $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\mathfrak{B}\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{B}$. As $\Omega$ is in every $\frak B$, it's also in the intersection. What you consider is called the [$\sigma$-algebra generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_an_arbitrary_family) by $\mathfrak{S}$ and is usually denoted by $\sigma(\mathfrak{S})$. But as you don't assmue that there is such a set $\Omega$ by assumption, the statement might be not true in general. But maybe this assumption is made in the book? As I don't have it, I don't know.

Comment: mag, Thank you very much for your answer. I am very new to measure theory. Is the definition of $\sigma$ algebra in the book by Kolmogorov and Fomin standard? I am afraid of that.

Comment: mag, I saw your link (Wikipedia). I guess the definition of $\sigma$ algebra in the book by Kolmogorov and Fomin is different from the standard definition of $\sigma$ algebra in Wikipedia.

Comment: I added it to the answer: the definition in the book of Kolmogorov is equivalent to the standard definition.

Comment: mag If $\mathfrak{B_1}$ and $\mathfrak{B_2}$ are two $\sigma$-algebras, then in general, I think the universe for $\mathfrak{B_1}$ and the universe for $\mathfrak{B_2}$ are not equal.

Comment: The authors don't assume that there is such a set $\Omega$.

Comment: Do they claim it to be a $\sigma$-algebra or was it an idea of you?

Comment: mag, The authors don't claim it to be a $\sigma$-algebra. I edited my question and added "Theorem 4" in this book.